# Headphone has no sound if fully inserted in jack

Tags: audio, laptop

When I connect my headphone to headphone jack in my laptop, I don't hear any sound. Unless I do not fully plug it in and instead just plug it in around 50%.

Sometimes I hear sound but it is all garbled.

This headphone used to work fine before and now it is giving me this problem for some time.

If I connect another headphone then it works fine so I don't think headphone jack is the problem.

Does anybody know why this is happening and how to fix it?

**EDIT**

Found a similar question. When I said that sometimes I head sound but it is all garbled then this is what I was talking about as discussed in this question.
[Why do speakers sound different when they're not fully plugged in?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13471/why-do-speakers-sound-different-when-theyre-not-fully-plugged-in?rq=1)

Comment: This is probably off topic, but have you tried different headphone/device combinations?

Comment: If another pair of headphones work fine it sounds like the headphones are the problem. Probably a loose or intermittent connection.

Comment: Related: [What is it that strips vocals from audio when a 1/8" audio jack is partially unplugged?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/42623/2028)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of the wires coming out of the plug has broken.  Cut off the plug along with a few inches of cable (to get past the point where a wire is broken), then solder on a new plug.